# What is paging in EEPROM?

Tags: eeprom

I have two questions regarding paging in EEPROM here:

1. What is paging in EEPROM?
2. In what situations is it normally used?

If you can provide an example with the AT24CXX that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paging in this context allows operations such as writing or erasing to be carried out on a number of locations at once instead of having to perform each one separately. EEPROMs such as the AT24CXX have a built-in controller to carry out write operations for you; you just provide it with the data you want written and it does the work and tells you when it's finished. This allows it to apply the correct timing and necessary number of write cycles to make sure the data is stored reliably while making the device last as long as possible.

If you look at the [AT24CXX datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0180.pdf), the section on Page Write shows you how to speed up the writing of large amounts of data by giving it the start memory address followed by a full or partial page of data values, and it then writes the page as a single operation. This makes it significantly faster than giving it an address and a data value and waiting for that to be written then repeating the entire process for each additional value.